# Assignment $(X,Y) \mapsto \nabla_XY$ is not a $(1,2)$-tensor for vector fields $X,Y$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

##### Exercise:

1. Let $\nabla$ and $\hat{\nabla}$ be two connections on a manifold $M$. Show that $\nabla - \hat{\nabla}$ is a (1,2)-tensor field on $M$.
2. Show that the assignment $(X,Y) \mapsto \nabla_XY$ is not a $(1,2)$-tensor for vector fields $X,Y$.

##### Solution to part 1:

The first part is done. Here we can show that
$$
\nabla_{fX}hY - \hat{\nabla}_{fX}hY = f(h \nabla_XY+X(h)Y)-f(h\hat{\nabla}_XY + X(h)Y) = fh(\nabla_XY = \hat{\nabla}_XY)
$$
Then by applying the statement:

---

Let $\mathcal{X}(M)$ denote the set of all differentiable vector fields on a manifold. An $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $A$ from $\mathcal{X}(M)^s, s \in \mathbb{N}$, to the set of scalar functions on $M$ is a $(0,s)$-tensor if and only if
$$
A(f_1X_1,...,f_sX_s)|_p = f_1(p)\cdot~... ~\cdot f_s(p) \cdot A(X_1,...,X_s)|p
$$
for arbitrary scalar functions $f_1,...,f_x$ on $M$ in every $p \in M$.

---

Then by this statement $A(X,Y) = \nabla_XY - \hat{\nabla}_XY$ is a $(1,2)$-tensor field on $M$.

##### Question:

Can someone explain to me, how I solve part 2? This part seems so easy but I am somehow struggling with this one.

Comment: Your statement is a if and only if statement.

Comment: Connections are generally denoted by $\nabla$, not $\Delta$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The question to address is whether $\nabla_XY$ is linear over functions in $X$ and/or in $Y$. (Presumably not, since that's the stated conclusion.)